# How to validate images array type using rule object with custom message in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Actually, I tried to create rule object which is able to validate every image type in array of images and not only enough but also, I must to show custom message in override message function in rule object.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ImagesArray implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
       return [$attribute => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png' ];
       here i need to validate these file types.

    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
        here, I need to show my custom messgae.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Request.
For example, create q request class: php artisan make:request MyRequest.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',            
    ];
}
public function messages()
{
    return [
      'image.mimes' => 'This image is not supported.',
    ];
}
```

}

In your controller import class MyRequest and in the method use MyRequest
e.g:

```
 public function store(MyRequest $request)
{ // your code
}
```

Let me know if that was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: this is form request, what if i have to use  Laravel rule object for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

When validating arrays or nested parameters, you should use `.` in your rules access a specific array index. but if you want to apply a rule to every index on that array, you can use `.*`.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
], [
    'image.*' => 'Invalid file type.',
]);
```

Or if you're using Request Forms

```php
public function rules(){
    return [
        'image.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
    ];
}
public function mesages(){
    return [
        'image.*' => 'Invalid file type.',
    ];
}
```

> For more info, see [Laravel's Documentation on Validation Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays)